# Модальное окно, с инпутами типа текст, меняющие фокус

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Имеется модальное окно.Взято из бутстрапа.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" 
 role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria- 
hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New 
 message</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-l 
 abel="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
   </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:. 
 </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:. 
 </label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
   dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send 
   message</button>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Сделать инпуты видимыми с границей, курсором только после нажатия, а так просто тексты в виде label.

Реализовать через ботстрап или css файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через css задайте инпутам `background: transparent; border: none` а при `:focus { background: ...; border: ...` стили которые  нужны при фокусе